# Showing a service along with specific view

Tags: android, service

I need to show a floating icon only along with a started maps activity and stop it when the map activity is gone.(when the user navegates back from the maps to my app) [floating service over maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4yQI.png)

```
 mIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FloatingIconService.class);
public void startTrip(String s , String d)
{
    Uri gmIntentUri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.co.in/maps/dir/" + s + "/" + d);
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,gmIntentUri);
    mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
    mapIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(mapIntent,4000);
    //view floating notes icon
    startService(mIntent);
}
```

onPause is necessary to keep the service runnig along with maps and onActivityResult doesnot do what I want

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    // To prevent starting the service if the required permission is NOT granted.
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M || Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FloatingIconService.class).putExtra("activity_background", true));
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == DRAW_OVER_OTHER_APP_PERMISSION) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Premission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    } else if (requestCode==4000 && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED || resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)){
        stopService(mIntent);
    }else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}


fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startTrip("USA", "Alexandria");
            }
        });
```

Comment: I have tried to override onRebind in the service class with no use